# Divergence Theorem and Green's first identity

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can anyone explain the underlined part in green. I know what green's identity is it's just I don't understand why we are summing over the surfaces of the holes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundary of $V$ consists of  $S_0,S_1,...,S_N$, although you need to be somewhat careful about orientation here.  Does that answer your question?